# Calculate SUM for specific columns for all the records in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite, prepared-statement

I have a table in SQLite, where each row represent a box.

```
CREATE TABLE "INVENTORY" (
    "product" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    "version" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    "orderB" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "AA" VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    "quantity" INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY ("product", "version", "AA", "orderB")
);
```

Boxes may have the same `product` and `version` value. How can I ask my DB to return me the total sums for all the boxes which have the same product and version?

One approach that I thought is to ask (I use `preparedStaments`) my DB for every product-version the query `SELECT SUM(quantity) AS total from INVENTORY where product = ? AND version=?";`

However can this be done just using SQL code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Product, Version, SUM(quantity)
FROM Inventory
GROUP BY Product, Version
```